# Thread in JME doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, jmonkeyengine

In JME I try to use threading but when I run the program the function never starts.

I have a server socket who is listening to input from Netbeans.

**Listener**

```
while (isRunning) {
            //Reads and prints the input
            String receivedString = (String) in.readObject();

            System.out.println(receivedString);

            String[] parts = receivedString.split(";");

            if(parts[0].equals("craneCon"))
            {
                final int containerId = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                m.enqueue(new Callable<Spatial>(){
                    public Spatial call() throws Exception{                        
                        m.removeContainersFromMaritime(containerId);
                        return null;
                    }
                });
            }
```

So in the main there is the function removeContainersFromMaritime

```
public void removeContainersFromMaritime(final int idContainer)
    {
        Node container = Maritime.listOfContainers.get(idContainer);

        martime.detachChild(Maritime.listOfContainers.get(idContainer));
        seagoingcrane.attachChild(Maritime.listOfContainers.get(idContainer));

        container.setLocalTranslation(0,5,0);
        System.out.println(Maritime.listOfContainers.get(0).getWorldTranslation().z);

    }
```

The connection is alright but the method is never executed. How can I fix this?

Comment: which method is not executed? what is m.enqueue?

Comment: The method removeContainersFromMaritime. The main is not static so I made the object Main m = new Main(); to call methods. Used this a an example http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:multithreading

Comment: @M.Jacobs: Did you call the 'start()' method on m? If this makes no sense to you, try my suggestion below! EDIT: you are only supposed to start one application, as in [this example](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:intermediate:simpleapplication)

Comment: If I try that I get this error: Uncaught exception thrown in Thread[LWJGL Rederer Thread,5,main] IllegalStateException; Scene Graph is not properly updated for rendering. State was changed after rootNode.updateGeometricState() call. Make sure you do not modify the scene from another thread! Problem spatial name: null

Comment: I don't want to use the simpleUpdate method in the main for updating the screen becauseI want to call methods from the listener so the screen is updated by them. Now is the main problem I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jMonkeyEngine uses a swing-style threading model where there is a single render thread that does all the work. Any changes to the scene graph have to be done from that render thread.

To get into the render thread you can implement `AppStates`, `Controls` or you can `enqueue` `Callable`s which are then executed on the render thread in a similar way to Swing's `invokeLater`.

The code snippet you posted looks about right, so assuming m is your running jME3 SimpleApplication then m.enqueue() will cause the enqueued callable to be executed next time around the render loop (i.e. at the start of the next frame).

If you are not seeing it executed then either:

1. Your application is not running
2. You created more than one application and enqueued it to the wrong one
3. The code is actually running and you just think it isn't.

Stepping through the code in the debugger and/or adding debug statements (for example breakpoint inside `removeContainersFromMaritime` to see if it is actually called should allow you to narrow this down.

Comment: I need some more clarification on this
1. what other threads exist in jmonkey apart from render thread. 2. Is there is single thread, how does input work if the thread blocks? 3. Which thread is responsible for notifying various listeners about events etc

Comment: @simar 1. Any threads you create. JME3 only uses the one. 2. It doesn't, if you block the thread everything stops, don't block the thread. (For example something that would block the thread is a good thing to farm off to another thread and then enqueue the results back to the render thread). 3. Depends what you mean but that sounds like the render thread too.

Comment: Which thread is when I receive callback from nifty onClick() method?
Suppose I have implemented one of my AppState as a controller and when I receive callback I do heavy computation there. What will happen to my input events? Will they get lost or they just queue up somewhere?
Could you point me to jmonkey code where I can see the update loop of render thread

Comment: @simar Nifty is also running on the render thread. Your best bet will be to gather your questions together and post them as new questions, this is the wrong place for it really. Feel free to post links to the new questions here once they are posted though.

Comment: one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200159/how-to-flush-all-input-events-in-jmonkey

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but what is "m" in m.enqueue(...)?
I'm guessing it is an executor service of some sort and it's probably where the problem lies.

You could try instead:

```
new Thread() {public void run()
{
    m.removeContainersFromMaritime(containerId);
}}.start();
```

It will at least show you if the problem is coming from "m" as an executor.

Comment: The method is in the main that why I made object Main m

Comment: See my answer, I'll answer this too :)